# IntelliJ: Viewing diff of all changed files between local and a git commit/branch

Tags: git, intellij-idea

Using IntelliJ's diff viewer is a very nice way to review code because you can make changes in your local version with all the capabilities of the IntelliJ code editor (refactoring, completion, etc).

Unfortunately, I have not worked out how to do the most important thing when you're doing code reviews in IntelliJ, namely: Looking at the diff of all the changed files in the working tree (checked out to the branch you want to merge from) and another branch (the branch you plan to merge into, e.g. "master").

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Please see the **Compare** section in one of their blog [posts](http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/03/simpler-and-more-powerful-ui-for-git-branches/).

Comment: This question shows the menu steps to display diffs for all files vs another branch (i.e. master):  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40637055/get-all-files-in-git-diff-in-intellij/55270244#55270244

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Though Jon Tirsen's answer is correct, you need to go through entire text in order to understand how to do that.

Here's the images of the same in mac.

1. I am currently working with hello_world and want to compare with master.

UPDATE: In the new UI, click on `Show Diff with Working Tree`

[image]

2. Next a window will pop up. Select `Files` and press `cmd + d`

[image]

3. Another window which shows diff. You can perform many different types of diff. Use `cmd + shift + ]` and `cmd + shift + [` to shift between files.

[image]

Diff Tip: IntelliJ provides advanced diff features. You can check those on the 3rd image.

Comment: How can I do this for the entire project, instead of file-by-file?

Comment: @JoeMjr2 I am really not sure if that capability is available today. You can navigate through all the files using `cmd + shift + [` and `cmd + shift + ]` (replace cmd with ctrl if you are using windows).

Comment: This has been changed in the 2020 version update, see my answer below for the updated method.

Comment: Can you compare 2 revisions also, by commit IDs?

Comment: Sadly, this modal is now changed to a tab view, which doesn't have the files diff. This answer is therefore outdated.

Comment: Use `cmd + d` to show the diff for any given file.  Unfortunately, I couldn't get `cmd + shift + [` and `cmd + shift + ]` to work in conjunction with this, so I had to navigate the tree to the next file. (replace cmd with ctrl if you are using windows).

Answer (score 118):

This has now been implemented. In order to compare two branches, you do:

1. Check out one of the branches you want to compare with.
2. Select the branch you want to compare with in the Git branch popup in the status bar in the bottom right of the IntelliJ window. A popup with some options is shown.
3. Select the "Compare" option.
4. This, by default, shows all the commits. You can also select the "Diff" tab to show the actual changes.

This is all described in much greater detail in [one of their blog posts](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2012/03/simpler-and-more-powerful-ui-for-git-branches/#Compare).

Comment: Is this also possible with arbitrary commits instead of branches? I mean I can quickly create a local branch for that, but that seems a bit cumbersome.

Comment: @Hikaru755 yes I created a `tmp` branch, I guess it is good enough. Seems like overkill though

Comment: @Robin yes you can. Open the file's history, select the two commits and press `Ctrl-D`. It works between different branches too.

Answer (score 73):

This has been changed in the 2020 version update:

You now need to do the following:

1. Checkout one of the branches you want to compare.
2. Open the *Branches* menu.
3. Select the other branch you want to compare with.
4. Select **"Show Diff with Working Tree"**.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I realized that it had changed but couldn't figure out where did it go.

Comment: This is the most up-to-date answer at this moment. Other answers are relevant to older IntelliJ versions, but not to the current one.

Comment: This is the best answer !!

Comment: The window closes when I select a file. Is there a way to bring it back without going through the menu again?

Comment: The option seems to have disappeared in a recent update? I can't find the "show diff with working tree" button

Answer (score 17):

This is implemented now. You right-click on the project and select "Git - compare with branch..." and choose `master` branch. Done. Diff all files.

Comment: This one is a good approach. If you see the option grayed out, it´s because you are not right clicking in the java/main/src project folder.

Comment: This method also allows you to compare against an _arbitrary commit_ instead of a branch. Just use "**Compare with Revision**" instead of "Compare with Branch".

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to compare your currently open file with another branch in a side-by-side fashion, just go to VCS -> Git -> Compare with Branch.

Comment: That answers a question, but not this one! :)

Comment: It's now: `Git -> Selected Directory -> Compare with Revision`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare the whole project.

- First. Select/click the project you are working on.
- Go to Git(tab) > Selected Directory > Compare with branch
- Then select the branch you want to compare. (ie origin/main)

Then you will get a tree of the different files between branches. You can select each one and compare, edit, delete, add anything you may need.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Right Click on the class and select the Git option where you will see compare with branch option where you can select the particular branch.