# How can I see the differences between two branches?

Tags: git, git-diff

How can I see the differences between branches `branch_1` and `branch_2`?

Comment: You want something different from the straightforward `git diff branch_1 branch_2`?  (Note, if the names branch_1 and branch_2 also name files, you need `git diff branch_1 branch_2 --`)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822811/differences-in-git-branches

Comment: The cited duplicate does not answer the question... Determining which files have changed with `git diff --name-status master..branchName` is markedly different than seeing the exact differences between branches with something like `git diff branch_1 branch_2`. Or maybe I'm missing something obvious...

Comment: Not only is the "duplicate" a different question, this question is the number one google match for "git diff two branches".

Comment: `git difftool branch..otherBranch` lets you SEE the differences in the Visual tool that you choose. e.g. Meld. This is the answer.

Comment: To restrict the diff to one `file` with the `..` syntax: `git diff branch1..branch2 file` or `git difftool branch1..branch2 file`.

Comment: in case you want to see the diff on IDEA https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825106/intellij-viewing-diff-of-all-changed-files-between-local-and-a-git-commit-branc/55159284

Answer (score 3912):

Use [`git diff`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff).

```
git diff [<options>] <commit>..​<commit> [--] [<path>…​]
```

`<commit>` is a branch name, a commit hash, or a shorthand symbolic reference.

Examples:

`git diff abc123..def567`

`git diff HEAD..origin/master`

That will produce the diff between the tips of the two branches. If you'd prefer to find the diff from their common ancestor to test, you can use *three* dots instead of *two*:

```
git diff <commit>...<commit>
```

To check which files differ, not how the content differs, use `--name-only`:

```
git diff --name-only <commit>..​<commit>
```

Note that in the `<commit>..<commit>` (two dot) syntax, the dots are optional; the following is synonymous:

```
git diff commit1 commit2
```

Comment: The same syntax works for comparing a branch with a tag or a tag with another tag.

Comment: The range syntax also works for `git log`. With that you can see the commit messages, and with the `--patch` option you can see a diff one commit at a time.

Comment: Note that you can also add a file or folder name after the above two commands.

Comment: So if the tripple-dot diff finds no common-ancestor differences, then that means `branch_1` has already incorporated all the changes in `branch_2` and a `git merge branch_2` (with `branch_1` checked out) will not affect `branch_1` at all.

Comment: @DanielZohar Yes, it should work with anything that is a valid commit reference! The git-scm book calls them 'tree-ish' or 'coimmit-ish'. Things such as `tags`, `branches`, `sha1`s, abbreviated `sha1`s, magic things like `HEAD`. (*Though you probably know that by now, since you posted that a year ago.*)

Comment: This doesn't work for me with remote branches.  It never returns anything.

Comment: @chiyachaiya your explanation helped me but git diff b1...b2 is not same as git diff b2...b1. For example once we started b2 from b1 and when if we make some changes to b1, git diff b2...b1 will show changes made to b1 after b2 started. If we do git diff b1...b2 it will give changes made to b2 which are not in b1.

Comment: Something I find useful as well is to print the differences out to a file using `git diff branch_1..branch_2 > C:\diff.txt`

Comment: And if you use one you just get an error.

Comment: chharvey: the order of args matters and will be reflected with different color  in the results (green vs red) since code that was added/deleted depends on the order of args.

Comment: Word for word copy of https://github.com/schacon/gitbook/blob/86d1d3061f32e07b56851833c6673e66a04fdbba/text/10_Comparing_Commits_Git_Diff/0_%20Comparing_Commits_Git_Diff.markdown http://schacon.github.io/gitbook/3_comparing_commits_-_git_diff.html

Comment: If you get `fatal: bad revision 'some-branch'` then this is probably a remote branch.  You probably need something like `git diff remotes/origin/some-branch my-local-branch`

Comment: is their a nice UI for this ie inside webstorm?

Comment: And why does it only work from the master branch?! (git 2.1.4) I have two repos, cloned from the same one. One has master checked out and the other one has... 'other'. From the 'other' branch:
$ git diff other..master
__fatal: ambiguous argument 'other..master': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.__

Comment: Clearly something has changed since this answer because

    $ git diff b1 b2
    fatal: ambiguous argument 'b2': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
    $ git diff b1 b2
    fatal: bad revision 'web-portal-hosts'
    $ git diff b1..b2
    fatal: ambiguous argument 'b1..b2': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
    $ git diff b1..b2 --
    fatal: bad revision 'ui-functional-tests..web-portal-hosts'

Comment: And if you wanna see the diff of a specific file between two branches:
`git diff branch_1..branch_2 -- filename`

Comment: this answer didn't help me. i did this instead: `git checkout local-branch` then `git log` to see which commit you want to see, then, `git diff master <hash-of-commit>` this is how u can see exactly what changes you made on your branch on each commit compared to master. (no one else uses my local branch except me.)

Comment: Two dots, three dots and two dashes all produce *"unknown revision or path not in the working tree"*. What is so broken with this tool?

Comment: git difftool -y b1..b2 (works with your configured difftool - in my case p4merge)

Comment: Doesn't work: `fatal: ambiguous argument 'branch1...branch2': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.`

Comment: If the two branches are very different, the order in which the branches are mentioned does not matter. However, if you know one branch is older than another branch then it will be easier to comprehend the output if you use `git diff <older branch>..<newer branch>`.

Comment: `git diff ..branch_2` compares the checked out branch to branch_2

Comment: In [the original text from which the answer was lifted](https://github.com/schacon/gitbook/blob/86d1d3061f32e07b56851833c6673e66a04fdbba/text/10_Comparing_Commits_Git_Diff/0_%20Comparing_Commits_Git_Diff.markdown) `branch_2` is named `test`.  As written here, the second sentence makes no sense.

Comment: @SaadRehmanShah, I didn't need the '--filename' to view changes of a specific file.
git diff <branch1>..<branch2> <path_to_file>
^^ This sufficed.
Hope this helps.

Comment: If you have the `fatal: ambiguous argument` error, you just need to follow [Dalin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/231914/dalin) 's comment and specify `remotes/origin` (or whatever your remote repo is called).

Comment: Can also specify path: `git diff BranchName1..BranchName2 --name-only -- /path/to/source/` .  `--name-only --` used only for file name

Comment: if you need to compare 2 commits in github - [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49838096/820410)

Comment: How do you then sift through the horrific UI of the `vi` text editor for each file?

Comment: In case you need to compare your current branch with other branch, you can do: ```git diff ...another_branch```

Comment: Your first and second lines are identical. It appears to me that you wanted to omit the dots in the first line...?

Comment: @Lazy Badger What does `[--]` mean?

Comment: Can the answer be edited to show an example of diffing two remote branches? I can't figure out how to get past the `fatal: ambiguous argument` even when I specify `remotes/origin` (after confirming my remote repo is called "origin").

Comment: @DarylSpitzer - `remotes/origin` **IS NOT** branch, it's repo, as you noted. You **must** use branches, as for local case, just prefixed with `remotes/` each remote branch

Answer (score 171):

Go to a branch (e.g. `main`), then run `diff` against another branch (e.g. `branch2`):

```
git checkout main
git diff branch2
```

Comment: this didn't work for me, it showed no changes. I only had local commits though.

Comment: Try preceding the branch name with the remote name, e.g. origin/

Comment: this is completely wrong. branch2 would have to be a tag or revision. Its a branch name that we want to compare not revision.

Answer (score 66):

```
git diff master..develop
```

Options:

- Add `--name-only` to only see the names of the files.
- Add `--  folderOrFileName` at the end to see the changes of specific files or folders.
- To compare the local branch with the remote one, then run `git fetch --all` to fetch all remote branches, and run:

  ```
  git diff --name-only [branchName]..origin/[branchName]
  ```

  Example: `git diff --name-only develop..origin/develop`.

Comment: `master` may be `main` now for your repo

Comment: This is not correct. This only works for revisions with the same name as the branch.

Answer (score 26):

You can simply show difference using `git diff b1...b2`, or you can show commit difference using `git log b1..b2`.

You can see the commit difference in a nice graphical way using
`git log --oneline --graph --decorate --abbrev-commit b1..b2`.

Comment: I didn't know about git log b1 b2, thanks!

Comment: personally I like the graph. It looks awesome when you work in multiple branches and merge them.

Comment: in this example, what are the values for `b1` and `b2`?

Comment: `b1` and `d2` is the name of two different branch

Answer (score 15):

There are many different ways to compare branches, and it's depend on the specific use case you need.

Many times you want to compare because something broken and you want to see what has been changes, then fix it, and see again what changed before commiting.

Personally when I want to see the diff what I like to do:

```
git checkout branch_1 # checkout the oldest branch
git checkout -b compare-branch # create a new branch
git merge --no-commit --squash branch_2 # put files from the new branch in the working folder
git status # see file names that changes
git diff # see the content that changed.
```

Using this solution you will see the diff, you can also see only the file names using `git status`, and the most important part you will be able to execute `branch_2` while seeing the diff (branch_2 is on the working tree). If something had broken you can editing the files and fix it. Anytime, you can type again `git status` or `git diff` to see the diff from the new edit to `branch_a`.

Answer (score 10):

Sometimes it's nice to see the diff as a tree...

`git difftool --dir-diff branch..otherBranch`

or to compare a remote branch to the local workspace...

`git difftool --dir-diff origin/branch .`

For example, when bitbucket [decides for performance reasons](https://bitbucket.org/blog/an-exciting-update-on-diff-and-merge-performance) it will [*only*](https://bitbucket.org/blog/improving-performance-on-complex-diffs) show you a "three way merge" diff rather than the actual complete differences between the two branches you've selected.

This will [show the diff as a tree](https://superuser.com/questions/1089475/is-it-possible-to-have-meld-open-all-files-at-once-when-used-with-git-difftool) in the tool you've selected. e.g. in meld.

Inspired by @GregRundlett comment.

Comment: I had neglected to link to the damning admission that they've removed a key diff capability to optimize their performance ('cost?').

Answer (score 7):

There are two ways to see the differences between two branches.The modifications that have been made to the files in each branch will be shown by these commands.

1. Use the `git diff` command to view the differences between two branches in a Git repository.

   `git diff branch1 branch2` will show all the differences.

   If you wish to compare a specific file between the two branches, you can use this command as:

   `git diff branch1 branch2 path/to/file`
2. The `git log` command can also be used to view the differences between two branches. Run the git log command with the —left-right parameter and the two branches you wish to compare like this:

   `git log --left-right branch1...branch2`

Comment: The second option is exactly what I was looking for. This is the perfect one-liner for a quick diff _by commit_. For an even quicker look. to refer to the current branch's position use `HEAD`, and to narrow to just commit messages add the aptly named `--oneliner` option. For example: `git log --left-right --oneline HEAD...branch2`

Answer (score 3):

I've tried most of the responses above. None of them work anymore because revisions and branches are completely separated. The responses with the lower rating are actually much closer to the correct answer.

The easiest solution is:

```
 git diff origin/branch1 origin/branch2
```

And the beauty of this is that this works even if you are on `origin/main` (in github/gogs) or `origin/master` (in gitlab).

Comment: "responses with the lower rating..." true. What will you do when this answer is #1?

Comment: I'll edit my comment to stay I'm "Der Beste"! To be honest the replies are not very old, so I don't know how they are correct. I've tested this on everything other than github.

Answer (score 1):

When on the feature branch, merge your target branch and then run a diff against it. For example, if you want to see what changes your `feature` branch add to `master`, do the following:

```
// Fetch from all remotes
git fetch

// Check out your feature branch
git checkout feature

// Merge origin/master to your branch
git merge origin/master

// Compare to origin/master
git diff origin/master
```

Answer (score 1):

### GitHub Branches Showing out-of-sync When They Weren't:

When Googling to understand why GitHub kept showing my branches out-of-sync when I was 200% they weren't, this question kept appearing at the top of the results pile. So I'll provide what I've learned to help other folks with the same question who land here.

### SOLUTION:

GitHub does ***[three-dot comparisons](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/proposing-changes-to-your-work-with-pull-requests/about-comparing-branches-in-pull-requests#three-dot-and-two-dot-git-diff-comparisons)*** (digested below) BY DEFAULT- **NOT** **TWO** dot:

> The two-dot comparison shows the difference between the latest state of the base branch (for example, main) and the most recent version of the topic branch.
>
> Since the three-dot comparison compares with the merge base, it is focusing on "what a pull request introduces".

### How to toggle between 2-dot and 3-dot branch comparisons on GitHub:

The URL of the diff'ed branches is presented as below with **THREE** dots:

```
https://github.com/yourAcct/yourRepo/compare/develop...main
```

Just backspace one of the three dots and GitHub will return the results of a **TWO** dot diff:

```
https://github.com/yourAcct/yourRepo/compare/develop..main
```

If your branches are truly in-sync, GitHub won't report any changes in the TWO-dot comparison.

### Conclusion:

GitHub doesn't expressly state how they are calculating the differences and I believe many like myself will see a message in GitHub that "*This branch is X commits behind*" and think: "*I must have made a boo-boo...*" Well, you didn't.

Not believing it was possible that GitHub was gaslighting me, I needed to prove the state of sync. It was only after this testing I knew something was wrong and continued investigating.

### Tests to prove my branches were sync'ed:

In all the tests below, **NO** changes were reported:

Test 1: LOCAL branches were in sync with each other:

```
git diff develop..main
```

Test 2: REMOTE branches in sync with each other:

```
git diff origin/develop..origin/main
```

Test 3: LOCAL branches in sync with their REMOTE counterparts:

```
git diff develop..origin/develop

git diff main...origin/main
```

Test 4: LOCAL branches were in sync with the other branch:

```
git diff develop...origin/main
git diff main...origin/develop
```

Only after validating my branches were in fact sync'ed could I consider the possibility the status returned by GitHub might not be what it appeared to be...

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse(J2EE version) ,  open "Window --> Show view --> Git Repository".
if you have checked out 2 local git branches for examples then you will have bunch of branches in Local section. select any 2 git local branches and do " right click and select "Compare with each other in Tree menu".

Open view "Git Tree Compare" and u will be able to see side by side diff for all files.

Answer (score 0):

For AzureDevOps users:

- Go to Repos / Branches

[image: branches list]

- On the right side, click on the sub menu next a branch

[image: menu]

- Select branches to compare

[image]