# In Git how can I see the diff from master to develop?

Tags: git

In Git how can I see the diff from master to develop?

I want to see everything that is not the same of the two branchs

Comment: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As explained in [these](https://stackoverflow.com/a/822859/1264909) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/822859/1264909) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9834872/1264909), you can do this by using [`git-diff`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-diff.html) to:

- View all the differences:

  ```
  git diff master..develop
  ```
- List files that are different:

  ```
  git diff --name-status master..develop
  ```

Answer (score 1):

`git diff [branch1] [branch2]` will do it for you.