# How to compare/diff specific version of master and fork repo in github

Tags: git, github, git-diff, git-fork

There are two repos on Github:

"Repo1" is a master that has regular commits (not yet forked by me)
"Repo2" is a fork of Repo1 from about 2 years ago (not yet forked by me)

I want to do a DIFF between the two Repos, based on the version of code in "Repo1" that was branched by "Repo2" (approx 2 yrs ago). My objective is to then get the most recent code from "Repo1", and the now isolated changes from "Repo2", and merge these into a new "Repo3", effectively bringing the changes added to a fork 2 yrs ago, into my new fork of the most recent code of "Repo1".

One of the issues I am having is when I try to fork more than one Fork form the same root/master it doesnt seem to work, just points me back to the first fork. I am thinking I need to clone everythign locally, and do the required work there then push back to a new clean merged repo?

Any guidance much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

> I try to fork more than one Fork form the same root/master

You don't have to fork more than one repo: fork only the repo you intent to contribute to (through PR - Pull Request). Here, fork Repo1, then clone it locally.

On your local clone, type:

```
git remote add /url/repo2
git fetch repo2
```

Then you can [diff between `master` and `repo2/master`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9834872/6309).

```
git diff repo2/master..master
```

See more at "[Showing which files have changed between git branches](https://stackoverflow.com/q/822811/6309)"

```
git diff --name-status repo2/master..master
```

---

The [OP qtime67](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2744193/qtime67) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2744193/qtime67):

> as Repo1 has moved on greatly since Repo2 was forked, I wish to first see only the core changes made between the original Fork (Repo2) and the version of Repo1 at the time the fork was made.

As described in "[`Git diff ..` ? What's the difference between having `..` and no dots](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7256391/6309)", that would be using three dots:

```
git diff repo2/master...master
git diff master...repo2/master
```

[image: http://sphinx.mythic-beasts.com/~mark/git-diff-help.png]

A three dots diff will diff from the common ancestor (`git merge-base foo master`)

Comment: Thanks Von - as Repo1 has moved on greatly since Repo2 was forked, I wish to first see *only* the core changes made between the original Fork (Repo2) and the version of Repo1 *at the time the fork was made*. This being the case how can I diff between specific versions of each?

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Both this and the explanation on differences using `..` and `...`. It helped me a lot.