# Git show file difference between original branch point and HEAD of current branch

Tags: git

I've branch from master do few commits and then I add lots of commits to master then how can show file difference between HEAD of the branch and commit from which I branch.

What I need is same diff I have when I create pull request on github, but from command line and for a branch.

The problem is that I don't know which commit was HEAD when I've run `git branch`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Show all changed files between two Git commits](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552340/show-all-changed-files-between-two-git-commits) or [Comparing two branches in GIT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834689/comparing-two-branches-in-git)

Comment: @Kleskowy I don't what commit I need to compare to. I need to get commit from the branch, Commit that was `HEAD` when I've run `git branch`.

Comment: Try $ [git lola](http://blog.kfish.org/2010/04/git-lola.html) then - I find it very useful: 
(or if you do not want to create any aliases: $ git log --graph --decorate --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit --all)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I don't what commit I need to compare to. I need to get commit from the branch, Commit that was HEAD when I've run git branch.

What you need is [`git merge-base`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge-base.html) to find the most recent common ancestor aka "the commit that was HEAD" when you ran git branch.

But to find the diff you can use this form :

> **`git diff [--options] <commit>...commit> [--] [<path>...]`**
>
> This form is to view the changes on the branch containing and up to the second
>   , starting at a common ancestor of both . "git diff
>   A...B" is equivalent to "git diff $(git-merge-base A B) B". You can
>   omit any one of , which has the same effect as using HEAD
>   instead.

---