# Generating diff file with git

Tags: git

it's a simple question, how do I generate a file that contains code difference between two branches for ALL files using git? I'm almost certain that I've seen it on stack overflow some time ago but I searched now and could not find it.

Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834689/comparing-two-branches-in-git

    git diff branch_1..branch_2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are planning to create a patch file and apply it, you can do

```
git diff branch1..branch2 --no-prefix > patchfile
```

followed by

```
patch -p0 < patchfile
```

to apply the patch.

If you want to just create a file, you can skip the `--no-prefix` option

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
git diff >> test.diff
```