# how to diff a local change to a specific branch?

Tags: git, branch, diff

here is the scenario i have, which i believe is pretty common:

1. file A on branch `master`.
2. i `fork master` into `feature`
3. now i add several commits on the feature branch changing file A.
4. i undo several edits (by editing the file more to remove the changes) so that the file is the same in branch master because my changes weren't that smart
5. i do a new change and want to see if i removed everything from before
6. my first try is `git diff master...`

but that shows the same diff from `git diff` it does not show the changes from master to now.

example contents and diff

```
$ git checkout master
$ cat a
line 1
line 2

$ git checkout feature
$ cat a
line 1-1
line 2-2
line 3
line 4

$ edit a #< from now on a is not indexed, it is locally edited
$ cat a
line 1
line 2
line 3

$ git diff
--- a
- line 1-1
- line 1-2
+ line 1
+ line 2
line 3
- line 4

$ git diff master...
--- a
- line 1-1
- line 1-2
+ line 1
+ line 2
line 3
- line 4
```

the diff i want to get is:

```
$ git diff ???
--- a
line 1
line 2
+ line 3
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Comparing two branches in GIT?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834689/comparing-two-branches-in-git)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Showing which files have changed between git branches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822811/showing-which-files-have-changed-between-git-branches)

Comment: to duplicate comments and downvotes: the reason for this question to even exist is because i confused this use case (un-indexed files) with the case in that question (files part of the tree). the accepted answer points out why i was (we are!) wrong in the assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do:

```
git diff master
```

without "..".

From: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff

```
git diff [--options] <commit> [--] [<path>…]
```

> This form is to view the changes you have in your working tree
>   relative to the named `<commit>`. You can use HEAD to compare it with
>   the latest commit, **or a branch name to compare with the tip of a**
>   **different branch**.