# merging remote git repo with local git repo

Tags: git

I have a Php project in Laravel framework.

Initial CODE STATE : A

One month later ,  another developer joins me.

After 6 months ,

My CODE STATE : A + B

His CODE STATE : A + C

B and C have many common files so we are expecting conflicts during git merge. We now wish to have a code base : A + B + C

My current status/strategy-in-progress : 
I have set up a remote git repository with code A + C and local git repository with A + B .

how to best merge remote git repository(A+B) with my local git repository(A + C) so that i  have A+B+C on the both local and remote git repo?

Please assist!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that `A + C` is in master, and `A + B` is in a pull request branch. If B and C modified the same files, they may cause merge conflicts with each other, so you want to resolve these before merging your pull request branch into master to make it easier to review and integrate. As a result, you should either merge master into your pull request branch (which will add a merge commit with parents B and C) or rebase your pull request branch against master (which will change your branch's commits to `A + C + B`).

Comment: Thank your for reply. If i create a pull request , i will have A + B in local. If i copy-paste my A+C into the folder then B is replaced by C..  Can you elaborate your solution so that how to merge C with the pull request. P.S.I am a beginner.

Comment: My current knowledge about git is what i learnt in git series by Jeffrey Way https://laracasts.com/series/git-me-some-version-control/

Comment: How ? "so you want to resolve these before merging your pull request branch into master to make it easier to review and integrate"

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to make two branches from `A`, for example: `MY_A` and `HIS_A` then you can add `B` and `C` to your branches: `MY_A + B` and `HIS_A + C` solve conflict, then try to add the rest of the work to both and choise the easiest to solve like this:

`MY_A + B + C` or `HIS_A + C + B`

but using branches you never lost your work and always you can do this localy for not alter the repository

**Update:**

first pull you master branch (`A+C`):

```
$ git pull origin master
```

then create a branch from master branch an create `AC`:

```
$ git checkout -b AC master
```

before change to the other branch ensure to have all your work commited

then create another branch from master branch an create `AB`:

```
$ git checkout -b AB master
```

here you are in other branch, you can add his code and commit it without worry about to delete or change files

see your branches use:

```
$ git branch
```

change to a branche `AC` use:

```
$ git checkout AC
```

change to branche `AB` use:

```
$ git checkout AB
```

Now you have two branches that you can see the diff
[read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834689/comparing-two-branches-in-git), and use `git diff AC..AB` to see the diference in the terminal, and what will happend if you do a merge between two branches.

Comment: Thank you for reply but the problem is I no longer have A,  I have only A+B and A+C. and i need A+B+C

Comment: Did you tried to make a diff between your:  A+B and A+C?

Comment: no .. how to diff between 'A+B' and 'A+C' . (I am on Ubuntu and i use Sublime text 3 editor)

Comment: take a look [at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834689/comparing-two-branches-in-git) you can use the command line or a graphic tools like smartGit to help you

Comment: [This](https://www.atlassian.com/git/?utm_source=bitbucket&utm_medium=link&utm_campaign=help_dropdown&utm_content=learn_git) is a good place to learn how to use git

Comment: Thankyou for your reply..How to create two branches - One with A+B and other with A+C ?If i clone the remote repo , i have A+C in my master branch ... If i copy-paste A+C in the cloned folder i lose changes of B

Comment: Where you have A+B? is it in another repository or you just have the code?

Comment: A+B is code.. not a repo.. i did git init to make it local repo