# How to get patch or diff file - Git comparison between branches

Tags: git, gitlab, diff, patch, atlassian-sourcetree

I need to get the **patch/diff** between the development and my feature branch.

How can I get this using `git` command.

Please consider the branch names be `development` and `test`. I need to get the differences from test and development branch.

Edit:

I have followed the steps provided in the below question:
[Comparing two branches in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834689/comparing-two-branches-in-git)

The differences are shown in the git terminal only.

How can I save the differences into a patch or diff file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing two branches in Git?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834689/comparing-two-branches-in-git)

Comment: @Yogesh_D Thanks for the link

Comment: @Yogesh_D I have edited my question and I need to get the patch file

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**try**

git diff development..test > patch_name.patch

this will create the patch. apply the patch wherever you want.

Answer (score 2):

You can also create a patch file using :
`git format-patch master..dev --stdout > patch.patch`

This creates patches in email format that I find a little bit more readable. Also note that the above command creates a single file for all patches.

These files can be applies to the repo using `git am`