# Different Commit between branches

Tags: git, git-branch, git-diff

I am using git. I did merge a origin branch with my local master branch. After this merge, I check status of the git using '`git status'`
command. Now I get the following result.

> Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 14 commits.

I just want to see what are the 14 commits that differs my master branch with origin/master? How can I see those 14 commits?

Comment: `git log origin/master..`

Comment: `A is ahead of B by N commits.`  To list the N commits, `git log B..A`.

Answer (score 0):

```
git diff <local branch> <remote>/<remote branch>
```

For an example, if the `git diff master origin/master`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. And I just want to see the commit code that differs with these two branches. Not entire diff list.

Comment: I think you are looking for this. 

https://stackoverflow.com/a/9834872/1281089

```git diff <local branch>..<remote>/<remote branch>```