# Changes not being pulled over with `git merge -squash master`

Tags: git

I've been using `git merge -squash master --strategy-option=theirs` on my release/staging branches. It allows me (as I understand) to take a snapshot of the current master branch into the release branch, but without all the hundreds of commits (each a new feature/bug fix) - instead they're all rolled up into a single commit ('Release 20180624' and 'Patch 1' etc) so I can quickly rewind to a nice set release point if I need to.

My issue is, after the `git merge -squash master --strategy-option=theirs` command, it's not bringing in all the changes. I just ran the command, and the `stage` branch, came up with an error compiling. I compare the two files, and on `master` and `stage` the file is different:

Master:

```
... loads of imports ...
import { CommentsModule } from '../comments/comments.module';
... loads more imports ...
import { routing } from './myjobs.router';
import { CommentsModule } from '../comments/comments.module';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
```

It's a simple error, the `CommentsModule` is imported twice.

Stage:

```
... loads of imports ...
import { CommentsModule } from '../comments/comments.module';
... loads more imports ...
import { routing } from './myjobs.router';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
```

Why does this difference exist? Almost everything else is identical - but now I feel I can't really trust the process. I've noticed this a few times, usually a single change like this (assuming there's nothing I've missed) in a random file. This time it was caught early because it was a nice compile error - but I can imagine there are other changes that are harder to spot. My release and stage branches don't accurately reflect my codebase.

Am I using `merge -squash` incorrectly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is that `git merge`—particularly the *to merge* combination of changes since a merge base—works on line-oriented differences and is not smart enough to understand that something should only be imported once.  Without `-X theirs` or `--strategy-option theirs`, if the change-sets don't match well, you will get a merge conflict.  Using `theirs` tells Git to blindly assume that where there is a conflict, it should use "their" version, but that *only affects conflicts*.  Even without `theirs` this can misfire.  For instance, suppose you added an import early:

```
[your changes near the top of the file]
 some context here
+import { CommentsModule } from '../comments/comments.module';
```

Suppose they decided to include this module many lines later:

```
 different context here
+import { CommentsModule } from '../comments/comments.module';
```

Git now sees instructions to add this same line twice, in different places, so it does that.

Both regular merge and squash merge perform the *to merge* operation.  The difference between them is at the end, when you or Git make the final commit.  With a regular merge, the new commit has *two* parent commits: your current commit, and the other commit you whose ID you passed to `git merge`:

```
...--o--*--o--o--...--o   <-- yourbranch (HEAD)
         \
          o--o---...---o   <-- theirbranch
```

becomes:

```
...--o--*--o--o--...--o--M   <-- yourbranch (HEAD)
         \              /
          o--o---...---o   <-- theirbranch
```

Without `--squash`, this becomes instead:

```
...--o--*--o--o--...--o--S   <-- yourbranch (HEAD)
         \
          o--o---...---o   <-- theirbranch
```

Note that the "squash merge" commit is an ordinary (non-merge) commit: it's not a merge at all!  The regular merge commit *is* a merge commit.  (This is a little bit of circular logic: a merge commit is simply a commit with at least two parents.  Still, that's the key distinction here.  Other than this, a `git merge --squash` is an ordinary merge, although it also forces `--no-ff` and `--no-commit`.)

Comment: I see, essentially it's because it's tracking the changes as it goes. Thanks for the explanation. I guess I'm stuck with it, it does seem there's a way to diff branches https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834689/comparing-two-branches-in-git so I can be assured that I can find all the differences at least!

Comment: Yes (though remember, each commit is a complete snapshot, not just a set of changes!). Note that `git diff A..B` is *exactly the same* as `git diff A B`: it tells Git to extract the commit identified by `A`, and the commit identified by `B`, and then compare these two snapshots. No branch relationship is required: just two commits. A branch name, in this context, refers to the tip commit on that branch—the one commit to which the branch name points directly.