# Merge two branches after bad partial merge

Tags: git, merge

I just did a bad thing with my git repo and I don't know how to solve it.
I basically have two branches, let's say `develop` and `feature`, which I constantly update. At one point I changed a couple of files on the branch `develop`. I also needed these changes in the `feature` branch, so instead of doing it again there I made a merge between the two branches only applying these changes (and discarding all the other files changes/conflicts). After that I just made some commits just to the `feature` branch.

That worked as I wanted but with a big problem. Now I need to merge the two branches (the `develop` into the `feature`) completely but when I try to do it nothing happens. I actually know why nothing happens (git thinks the two branches are already merged and the only changes are in the `feature` branch. It's the same as I try to merge a branch that I just created) but I still need to complete the merge with the old changes.
To better understand this in the situation example:

```
develop  o--c--1-- --2-- --o- 
             \              \
feature       \ --o-- --b-- -\m--o-

b: commit before wrong partial merge
1: changes applied in the m commit (after wrong merge
2: changes NOT applied in the m commit (after wrong merge
m: result of partial merge
```

As explained in the `m` commit I just have the changes of the `1` and not the changes of the `2`. If I try to merge the `develop` into the `feature` now the `2` changes are lost.

I came up with a couple of solutions but I'm not sure if any of that can actually work:

1. I could checkout to the `b` commit so I can merge all the changes from the `develop`. Then I can commit the changes and merge them with the current `feature` branch
2. I could create a complete new branch (let's say `temp`) from the `c` commit. Then I can copy all the content of the `feature` branch into the temp branch without actually merging but just copying the files. Then I commit the resulting changes and then merge the new `temp` branch with the `develop`. Finally I can copy the resulting content to the `feature` branch so it's stay aligned.

I think that the second option could actually work well but I'm not really sure.

To finish, in the second option I tried to save the `feature` branch to keep the repo in order. But I don't really need to preserve the `feature` branch as I would delete it soon or later when the feature is actually complete.

Anyone knows a better way to help me with this problem?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `git cherry-pick`.

```
develop  o--o--1--2--3--4--o- 
             \              \
feature       o--o--o--o--o--o--o-
```

If first commit is already in your feature branch then:

```
git checkout feature
git cherry-pick {second-commit-hash}
git cherry-pick {third-commit-hash}
git cherry-pick {fourth-commit-hash}
```

Then you can [compare branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834689/comparing-two-branches-in-git) to be sure that your `feature` branch differs from your `develop` branch only in changes that you've really introduced in it.

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. I'll let you know if it all goes well