# git - Is there a way for me to literally diff 2 branches?

Tags: git

I find sometimes I like to compare 2 branches using a diff tool that knows nothing about git.

So basically, a way to do a git diff that isn't version control aware.

For example, assume I had 2 branches I wanted to compare, `master` and `develop`.

#### What I've been doing is

- checking the repo out into 2 folders

  - `myrepo_master` -> myrepo checked out to master
  - `myrepo_develop` -> myrepo checked out to develop
- using some tool, like [DiffMerge](https://sourcegear.com/diffmerge/) to compare the 2 folders.

**Is there a way to do this with git itself, without having to check the branches out to 2 separate folders?**

Comment: Did you rule out just configuring and using a [difftool](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-difftool)?

Comment: Yeah I do use a difftool, but it just seems to be the tool that's used to diff an individual file, not the repo in general.

Comment: Try `git difftool -d ` + the branches, see what happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe just do:

```
git diff master..develop
```

Reference: [Comparing two branches in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834689/comparing-two-branches-in-git)

Comment: That seems to work, and as mentioned by @Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen, `git difftool -d master develop` seems to work, and uses the difftool I have configured as well