# How to show the list of of files changed in a branch

Tags: git

Is there a way in git which shows the list of files being changed in a whole branch?

I find the post about showing how to list all the files in a commit:

[How to list all the files in a commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424071/how-to-list-all-the-files-in-a-commit)

Is there a way to do that for all the commits in a branch?
And how can list all the commits in a branch?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Comparing two branches in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9834689/comparing-two-branches-in-git)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Mitchel Paulin noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63985992/1256452), commits hold *snapshots*, not changes.  You must pick two snapshots and ask Git to compare them, before you can find any differences.  Consider this the equivalent of a [spot the difference puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spot_the_difference): each commit snapshot is a *full picture* of your source, and you have to put up *two* pictures before you can see what's different.

The question to which you linked, [How to list all the files in a commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/424071/1256452), has a lot of answers, but none of them note the fact that each commit actually holds two things: a snapshot *plus* some metadata.  That is:

- Each commit is numbered.  The numbers are big ugly hash IDs—they look like random strings of letters and digits—but these are actually numbers.  Every commit gets its own unique number.  (They're actually cryptographic checksums.)
- Each commit stores a full snapshot of every file—not changes, a snapshot.  The files in each commit are frozen for all time, and to save space, are de-duplicated across all commits (since many commits share most of their files with many other commits), but each one has a full copy.
- Each commit stores some *metadata* such as the name and email address of the person who made the commit.  One of those metadata items, though, is the commit number of the *previous* commit.  Git calls this the *parent* of the commit.

These parent links mean that Git actually works backwards.  That is, a branch is just a chain of commits that ends with some particular commit:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

Here `H` stands in for the big ugly hash ID of the last commit in the chain.  Inside commit `H`, Git has stored the hash ID of earlier commit `G`.  We say that `G` is `H`'s parent, or that `H` *points to* `G`.

When you have Git show you what *changed* in some commit like commit `H`, Git is really extracting both `G`'s snapshot *and* `H`'s snapshot, and then comparing them.  Whatever is different, that's what changed.  If you just want the names of the changed files, that's particularly easy for Git, because of the de-duplication trick it uses.

But this also leads to the answer to the other part of your question:

> Is there a way to do that for all the commits in a branch? And how can list all the commits in a branch?

If `H` is the *last* commit in a chain of commits, and `H` points to `G`, then `G` is the next commit backwards.  Git can thus use `H` to find `G`.

Commit `G`, meanwhile, holds the big ugly hash ID of its parent `F`, so Git can use `G` to find `F`.  That lets Git step back one more step.

`F` also holds the hash ID of *its* parent, so from `F`, Git can step back to the next—well, *previous*—commit.

This is just what `git log` does: it starts at the end, and works backwards.  Almost all of Git does this same thing, working backwards.

A *branch name* like `master` or `branch1` just holds the hash ID of that *last commit*.  When you add a new commit to a branch, Git stores the new commit's hash ID into the branch name right then and there, and now the new commit is the last commit.

There's another tricky bit though:

```
             I--J   <-- branch1
            /
...--F--G--H
            \
             K--L   <-- branch2
```

Which of the two branches are commits up through `H` on?

Git's answer is: *they're on both branches*.  In fact, in a real repository, *most* commits are on *most* branches.  Running `git log` from `branch2`, say, will start at `L`, move back to `K`, move back to `H`, move back to `G`, and so on, all the way back to the very beginning of time in the repository.

When someone asks about all the commits on some branch, they almost always don't really mean what they're asking.  They almost always mean *on some branch, backwards, until some point where I think Git should stop early*.  Git makes you tell it, explicitly, where to stop.  That's what the `git log branch1..branch2` syntax is about: it says *commits you find by working backwards from `branch2`, but excluding commits you find by working backwards from `branch1`*.  Here, that would be commits `K` and `L` only, starting with `L` and going back to `K`.  The next commit back—`H`—is on `branch2`, but it's also on `branch1`, and we told Git to leave out *all* `branch1` commits, so that leaves out `H`, and `G`, and everything before them.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Changes only make sense when relative to something else. For example, you could do a diff against some branch (say master) with the following `git log branch1..branch2`.

Or maybe `git diff --name-status branch1..branch2`