# diffing unstaged or uncommitted changes in IntelliJ Idea

Tags: git, intellij-idea

In the IntelliJ Idea IDE, how do I do the equivalent of plain ol' `git diff` (ideally `git diff -w`) or `git diff --staged`, so I can view my changes side-by-side with my branch's HEAD? I basically want the same thing as *Project Explorer → Compare With → HEAD Revision* in Eclipse Juno.

I've found out how to [compare different branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825106/intellij-viewing-diff-of-all-changed-files-between-local-and-a-git-commit-branc) in IntelliJ, but I haven't worked out how to do this basic thing―the current branch does not appear as an option in *Project tree → Git → Compare with Branch...*. An [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23057258/1450294) explains how to do it for one file, but this doesn't work for the whole project or even an individual directory, only individual files.

I'm using IntelliJ for the first time in 8 years, so I'm probably missing something obvious. Unfortunately, the resident IntelliJ expert is completely new to Git. ;-)

Comment: I just hit Cmd+K (the commit shortcut) and it brings up all the files I've changed in the current branch.  You have to click on each file to see the diff though.   I find this to be pretty useful, but I wish it wasn't a modal dialog.

Answer (score 3):

You can see the diff of the opened file by going to Main Menu -> VSC -> GIT -> Compare with same Repository Version.

There is also a shortcut [image] in the toolbar, using which you can directly view the diff of the opened file.

Comment: Thanks. But what I really want is to diff the entire repo, so I know what I'm about to commit. This feature only seems to handle one file at a time. (It's disabled in the context menu when I right-click a directory in the project view, but enabled for individual files. D'oh!)

Comment: In VCS menu -> Show Changes View  OR Version Control Tool Window you can see the list of all changed files. You can open a file and continue to click next change. At end of file it will itself open the diff in next file. Or press ⌘Shift ] to directly go to next file.

Comment: Oh, so 'next change' goes across files... I suppose that helps a bit. File trees showing changes is something I really miss from Eclipse, though!

Answer (score 3):

You can use Version Control window to see all changed files (⌘-9). Then you can select file and press ⌘-D to view diff for it.

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I'm not currently using IntelliJ, so I can't verify that this works, so I haven't yet accepted any answer. Also, I don't have a Mac, so I don't have a clover-splat key. Would you happen to know the keyboard shortcut in Linux, or could you specify the menu path?

Comment: On Linux it is Alt+9 to view changed files list (menu item View→Tool Windows→Version Control), then Ctrl+D to open a file's diff.
The feature is documented here https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/version-control-tool-window-local-changes-tab.html.

Answer (score 2):

Press Alt+9 to get the "Local Changes" view that has the information you required

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/version-control-tool-window-local-changes-tab.html