# Is there any way to compare two files in Git without their formatting changes?

Tags: git, github, git-svn

I have committed some code with some format but the origin has some other format. The reviewer is asking me to revert all my changes and I am searching for some UI tool or some way in Git to remove formatting and give the actual result.

Comment: Have you heard of `git diff`? If not you can read up on it here: http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff

Comment: Save two files, old and new, and diff them with sublime text. If your formatting issue is tabs vs spaces (repo owner is kinda a jerk then), Sublime will also allow you to convert. Under View->Intention.

Comment: I am using git diff and its showing all line changes as formatting is different for both files.
I am little novice in GIT and i want to use git UI insted of commands 
In SVN i used to copy my file and origin file in an diff tool and used to compare them.
But now In GIT i cant copy both files sepratly from GITHUB.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you might have a look at git diff, in particular the two following options:

```
-b, --ignore-space-change
   Ignore changes in amount of whitespace. This ignores whitespace at line end, and considers all other sequences of one or more whitespace characters to be equivalent.

-w, --ignore-all-space
   Ignore whitespace when comparing lines. This ignores differences even if one line has whitespace where the other line has none.
```

So running `git diff --ignore-all-space`

However, if what you define by formatting is not just whitespace, I guess you have to do it by hand

Comment: Thanks alot i guess this will solve my 50% problem but still need to figure out formmating stuff.

Comment: I am using eclipse default formatter and reviewer is using intelij formatter so when he commits format changes and when i commit format changes ibasically i mean Placing of brackets ,breaking method Name etc So after removing white spaces also i can see some changes which i have not done

Answer (score 1):

If you use `intellij`, consider using the `version control` tool provided by it.

The below link details on how to get a diff between two branches. https://stackoverflow.com/a/49642681/2960555

for a single file diff, You can right click on file -> git -> compare.

A new window will gets opened. select ignore options in that.

Answer (score 0):

Kdiff3 is the tool i needed to get my work done
This is a GUI tool for UNIX systems which can compare two file remove conflicts check for changes