# how maintain my code format with origin code

Tags: git, pycharm

When i checkout code from other git repository(for example springboot github repository)  and I modify some file of it. Then i format the code with pycharm . after that ,commit and push the code ,But the format of code is changed. So I cannot know which line is modified.
So I want to know is there has a way let pycharm fomat code use origin code format.
In this way I know Where is modified When i see git logs.

This question is the same with other ide (intelij,pycharm,webstorm and so on )

thx

Comment: I thnik your question is unclear. "is there has a way let pycharm fomat code use origin code format" <- What does it mean? Could you explain me this?

Comment: Note: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31053137/6309