# get all files in git diff in intellij

Tags: git, intellij-idea, version-control, diff

Is there a quick way to open all files with a diff between 2 commits in intellij?

Im looking at my diffs in gitlab and Im thinking itd be easier to just do the edits there, yet I want the benefits of the IDE so to speak.

Comment: It is 5 years later and still without solution. For idea 2021.2.2 IC I can selecting two commits and using "Compare Versions" from context menu I can see all changed files BUT cannot open them all and it was the goal of this question. I need such functionality to for code reviews and want to run inspections only on files from diff.

Comment: I created a ticket for that functionality https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-278659

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think this is the closest solution you can have.

- Open ***Version Control*** tool window.
- Go to ***Log*** tab.
- You can see the network diagram. Select ***2 commits*** that you want ***to compare***.
- Then from the right hand side you can see the ***list of diff files*** between 2 commits.

[image]

- Further you can select a file from the list and, click on top left red color button (Diff button) on the file list window and ***see the diff for that file***. And you can iterate forward and backward through the list of diff files by the ***next*** and ***back*** buttons (keyboard shortcuts too) on top left on diff window. :))

[image]

Comment: Bit more: It looks like I have to shift click 2 commits to get all the diffs. Click the diff for that file means I can then flip through all the diffs listed using next and back buttons in the top left. This is going to be the best solution I can get, I figure the Gitlab layout is still slightly more intuitive in this sense. Thanks you.

Comment: @PaulStanley thnk you very much, I added your detail too. :))

Comment: Update: In a current version (2019.2) you have to select two commits from the log (ctrl+click), then right-click on one of them and select "Compare Versions". You then get a window with all the changed files and can get a Diff by selecting a folder or file and clicking on the "two blue arrows"-button. ;)

Comment: For idea 2021.2.2 IC that answer is not valid. Selecting two commits with Ctrl or Shift is showing in panel on right only files updated in those commits - not files changed between those commits. However after selecting two commits and using "Compare Versions" from context menu I can see all changed files BUT cannot open them all and it was the goal of this question.

Answer (score 7):

This is easy to do through the IntelliJ IDEA menu system.

Suppose you are working on a branch `cool-feat` and you want to compare all files against branch `master`.  Starting at the top menu, select:

```
VCS -> Git -> Branches
```

a pop-up menu will appear.  Then, select:

```
master -> Compare with Current
```

A comparison window will open, showing all the commits since branch `cool-feat` was created.  Select the tab `Files`, then select the first icon in the top-left corner under the word 'Difference', which looks like 2 arrows pointing inward (you can also use cmd-D).  This brings up the file comparison window, with the current version of a file (branch `cool-feat`) on the left, and the version from `master` on the right (the git commit sha and lock symbol indicate this).

You can use the up/down arrays in the top left corner to jump between changed source lines.  I have remapped keys alt-upArrow and alt-downArrow to make this easier.

Answer (score 4):

`VCS => Browse VCS Repository => Show Git Repository Log` or `Right clik` on the file `=> local history => Show History` for one file