# IntelliJ show GIT differences after commit

Tags: git, intellij-idea, version-control

First, I create new branch. Then, I add a new code line in my class. Intellij shows on the left with a different color that I added a new line. Then, I commit my code. After this, IntelliJ no longer shows that I added new line on the left. I don't want that.

How can I configure IntelliJ so it would show all the changes that have been done, compared to, for example, another branch or commit from before?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ: Viewing diff of all changed files between local and a git commit/branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825106/intellij-viewing-diff-of-all-changed-files-between-local-and-a-git-commit-branc)

Comment: Not really a duplicate, because this question is about the diff markers in the editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately having diff markers in the editor with respect to some earlier commit is not possible right now in IDEA.
Here's the ticket in JetBrain's issue tracker:

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-24398

Please vote for it and comment on it.

Answer (score 1):

Changes with different color as you found only show the **changes which are not committed**. After you commit changes, there won’t show the new lines on the left (also as you found) since there is no changes need to be committed.

If you want to **compare the changes which have already committed**, you can select a commit and then show diff. Detail steps as below:

Version Control -> Log -> select a commit -> show Diff.

[image]

Then you will get the changes by compare with the previous commit.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Install Git Scope Plugin: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10083-git-scope

Rubymine version 2020.2.3 on Mac

1. Open Rubymine
2. Open Preferences (keyboard shortcut: command + ,)
3. Navigate to Plugins
4. Search for Git Scope
5. Install & Restart Rubymine
6. Navigate to View > Tool Windows > Git Scope
7. See documentation for further instruction: https://bitbucket.org/comodmw/git-scope/src/master/