# shortcut to show git diff with origin master when working on a different branch with intellij

Tags: git, intellij-idea, diff

I tend to check `git diff with origin master` using `intellij` many times a day and it has become a `laborious` task for me.

I use git diff tool provided by intellij...as suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49642681/2960555

Is there a way to `add shortcut` for this manual steps.

Answer (score 6):

As I see, you can assign a shortcut for `Compare with Branch...`, but not automatically select the `origin/master` or any other branch.

To make it, go to Settings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>) → `Keymap`, select `Version Control Systems` → `Git` → `Compare with Branch...`, right click on it and select `Add Keyboard Shortcut`.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Since you need to check the diff often, a permanent view that shows the diff might be helpful. Starting with 2019.2 there is something that could help.

Since 2019.2 Branches filter in the Log tab supports `ref1..ref2` filter that shows commits present in one branch but missing from another. So you can have a Log view that shows the diff between your current branch and master using the `HEAD..master` (commits of your current branch not present in master) or `master..HEAD` (commits of master not present in current branch) filter.

[image: Log tab]

To have the view always available, just create a second Log tab (highlighted 2 on the above). ANd from this view, you could call Compare with local on any revision to get the list of files that are different between your working tree and corresponding revision.

[image: Compare with local]

BTW, you can assign a shortcut to the Compare with Local

Answer (score 2):

(Ctrl + Alt + S) → Keymap, select Version Control Systems → Git → Compare with the Same Repository Version, right click on it and select Add Keyboard Shortcut.

That works for me ;)

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> for VCS Operations. <kbd>6</kbd> Show Diff. Very fast, standard, shortcut.

The hashes shown refer to the commit which last modified this particular file (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> is context sensitive). You can see this in the History tab of the Git tab (<kbd>4</kbd> Show History). Like this:

[image: Pycharm with Git tab up with History selected, and VCS Operations shortcut pop up showing]

You can verify this in GitHub or `git log README.md` (or whatever the file in question is called).

VSC Operations don't give us these options if the project is not under source control:

[image: VSC Operations option for brand new project, without Git]