# Is there a way in Android Studio to see all local changes in a single diff window?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, version-control, diff

With other editors I used it was possible to see *all local changes in a single diff window showing the unified diffs off all files one after the other*, so if I changed 3 files for example then I could simply scroll through the changes in a single window without having to select the files separately for diffs.

Here's an example of what I mean from magit which shows all changes in a single window:

[image]

Is there a way to do this is Android studio?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IntelliJ: Viewing diff of all changed files between local and a git commit/branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9825106/intellij-viewing-diff-of-all-changed-files-between-local-and-a-git-commit-branc)

Answer (score 3):

Right-click on your project in project structure on the left. 
then `Local History` -> `Show History`. If you want to show history only for **src** folder, click on it.. the same for layout folder etc..

It will open in one separate window and shows diff between changed and file before changes.

Comment: It still shows file diffs separately and I have to click on the files. I'd like a single unified window which shows all the local diffs in a single window, all diffs of changed files one after the other. It makes it very convenient to check all the changes before commit withouth having to click on anything or switching between files.

Comment: Here's an example of  what I mean from magit which shows all changes in a single window:  https://magit.vc/screenshots/commit-top.png

Answer (score 3):

Try Version Control on the bottom left of Android Studio:

[image: bottom left toolbar]

It lets you choose between the unified viewer and a side-by-side view:

[image: view dropdown]

Comment: Side-by-side view is useful, and should be sufficient. However, being able to arrange tabs is rather useful when refactoring with many small changes that cascade across multiple modules. Coupled with the overall lack of UI response I just don't see Android Studio providing the same level performance that VS does, especially with ReSharper plugged in.