# How can I compare two commit in different branches with Git in Android Studio 4.1?

Tags: git, android-studio

I use Git in Android Studio 4.1. There are two commit in different branches.

The first commit is named "TestC 47" located in "TestC" branch, the second commit is named "Dell_Merge 25" located in "master" branch.

I hope to know what are different between "TestC 47" commit and "Dell_Merge 25" commit, how can I do?

**Image 1**
[image]

**Image 2**

[image]

Comment: vocabulary : in `git` you say "a commit", not "a submit"

Answer (score 3):

If those commits represents the respective HEAD of their branch, you can simply compare branch, as described in [this article](https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-use-git-in-android-studio-part-2-93cec67b91b0) ("**How to Use Git in Android Studio**" from [Minh Pham](https://vn.linkedin.com/in/pdminh))

> Suppose I’m in the feature branch, and I want to compare it with the master branch. Go to “VSC” -> “Git” -> “Branches”, select the master branch and choose “Compare with current”.
>
> [image: https://miro.medium.com/max/597/1*IwC5W6KLmZngioTbo1dVlQ.png]
>
> A popup “Compare feature with master” shows up with all the differences between the two branches, commits to commits, files to files.
>
> [image: https://miro.medium.com/max/955/1*XAT0jg4LK7zPKEvt448Agg.png]

The same idea applies for two arbitrary commits: you can create two temporary branches tmp1 and tmp2, and compare those two branches as described above.

[Android Studio 4.1](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases#4-1-0) (Aug. 2020) is based on [IntelliJ IDEA 2020-1](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/04/intellij-idea-2020-1-released/), so you can also follow the [compare branches illustrated here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61707543/6309).