# How to view all differences between two git commits within Intellij?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I looked at a few results for how to do the task in the title. One of the most popular is an SOF answer here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49642681/1056563

In particular there is this popup shown:

[image]

However when I do apparently the same process the popup does not include those `compare` options:

[image]

What do I need to do to get the compare commits option?  I am on `Intellij Ultimate 2020.2` on macOS.

**Update** The (now rather tentatively..) accepted answer refers to a link to `Compare Versions`. Here is my attempt to replicate those instructions. However there is no "compare versions" option afaict:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Review the differences between two commits﻿ (From IntelliJ docs)**

IntelliJ IDEA allows you to check which files were modified between two commits instead of having to browse the changes in each commit in between.

Select any two commits in the Log tab of the Git tool window
⌘(Сmd) 9 and choose the 2 commits you want to compare Versions from the context menu.

The Changes tool window with a list of files modified between the selected commits opens.

You can view the diff for any file by clicking the Show diff icon or pressing ⌘(Сmd) D.

Comment: Wow so simple, but I did not use the `log` panel before

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to compare two commits in IDE then please open Git toolwindow, find in a log desired commits, select them while holding Ctrl and then you can hit cmd/Ctrl+D or right-click and choose "Compare version".
Please see more [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/investigate-changes.html#compare-versions) about commit and history review
[image]

Comment: The downside of this is I have to find a particular file _that actually changed_ in  a given commit.

Comment: Can you please share how you opened the `git tool window`  and show a screenshot of it?    I am actually uncertain what you mean here.  There is a  `Git` from main menu but it does not have the feature you mention afaict

Comment: I have put a screenshot in my question.  I do not see how to "Compare versions" as referred to by that link   I am going to unaccept this answer temporarily. If you can provide more clarity i'd be glad to re-accept.

Comment: @StephenBoesch As I can see from a screenshot you've already Opened git toolwindow (the log located under that toolwindow). So, please click on these two commits while holding Ctrl and then hit cmd/Ctrl+D or right-click and choose "Compare version"

Comment: This does not actually consistently work: the "compare versions" does not (usually at least) show up.  I am actually still at a loss how to compare commits